# Split string by patterns, and map resulting tokens to respective pattern in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

I have a string consisting of a set of patterns. An example of such a string of patterns would be `{yyyy}{mm}{dd}_{country}_{state}_jobsreport.{type}`. I replace each pattern in the string with a regex (Eg - `yyyy` gets replaced with `([1-9][0-9]{3})` representing all possible values of years). Based on this regex, I query and get a file with filename following the regex, eg - `20200331_japan_kyushu_jobsreport.json`.

Now I need to map each token to its corresponding pattern. Eg -

```
year = 2020
month = 03
date = 31
country = japan
state = kyushu
type = json
```

Things to note -

1. Ordering of patterns - The ordering of patterns is not fixed. For example, in our case the pattern could have been `{country}-{yyyy}{mm}{dd}-sometext-{state).{type}`, and the resulting filename could be `usa-20200331-sometext-florida.txt`. (The relative ordering of yyyymmdd is fixed though).
2. Delimiters - There is no specific delimiter. For `20200331_japan_kyushu_jobsreport.json` the delimters are `{"_",".","jobsreport"}`. Similarly for `usa-20200331-sometext-florida.txt` the delimiters are `{"-",".","sometext"}`

How can I approach this mapping in PL/SQL? Normal functions like `REGEXP_SUBSTR` work on a fixed set of delimiters, whereas the delimiters here can be varied.

Comment: Have you tried making a function, which returns this as a varchar2 string? If no, you could quite easily make a function that concats the string in order. And just adds the string to the so-far built string.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function. If this is a set rule that the same values will always pop up you can do something along the lines of:

```
CREATE FUNCTION BuildFileName
( 
    param varchar2
) return varchar2
AS
    variable1 varchar2(100);
    variable2 varchar2(100);
    variable3 varchar2(100);
    v_cstring varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
    begin
        SELECT 'v1',null,'v3'
        INTO variable1, variable2, variable3
        FROM dual;
        exception when no_data_found then
        return null;
    end;
    
    IF variable1 IS NOT NULL THEN
        v_cstring := v_cstring || variable1;
    END IF;
    
    IF variable2 IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF substr(variable2, length(variable2), 1) NOT IN ('_', '.') THEN
            v_cstring := v_cstring || '_';
        END IF;
        v_cstring := v_cstring || variable2;
    END IF;
    
    IF variable3 IS NOT NULL THEN
        IF substr(variable2, length(variable2), 1) NOT IN ('_', '.') THEN
            v_cstring := v_cstring || '.';
        END IF;
        v_cstring := v_cstring || variable3;
    END IF;
    
END BuildFileName;
```